# Override GetWebRequest method to switch HTTP1.1 to 1.0

Tags: c#, web-services, http, cisco-axl

I am using `Cisco AXL web service` in `.NET`.

The problem is, it does not allow me to override `GetWebRequest` method to change HTTP version.

I am following this document that gave me the following code to add http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/devguide/9_1_1/axl.html#wp1055254

```
 protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
 {
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
    request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
    return request;
 }
```

I have this code inside the class that extends `SoapHttpClientProtocl`. I googled around and I have found people with the same problem but no clear answer of how to solve it. I'm hoping that somebody has an answer here .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what fixed it but here is what I did,

1.) I added the WSDL as a service reference although I used wsdl.exe to compile the API.

2.) Switched .NET framework to 4.5 instead of 4.0 Client profile.

3.) put the compiled code in the project's directory although I did step 1.

4.) Uncommented a lot of the autogenerated code that I know for sure I will not use and the debugger was complaining about a XmlSerializer error.

5.) Turned on "Just my code" from Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

6.) moved some of the code that Cisco wanted us to add to separate classes and made calls to them inside the auto generated code.

Hopefully this would help somebody some day!!